# Can't add data to sqllite database if using JavaScript redirect after adding

Tags: jquery, sqlite, redirect, insert

I'm developing a phonegap application . All the things run well except one headache problem

I can insert the data into the database successfully. But if I add a JavaScript redirect code after the insert code, the data will not be added to database successfully. Below is the related code:

```
function insertDeadlineToDB(dbId,dbDescription,dbClass,dbDueDate, dbDueTime, dbType, dbAdditionalInfo) {
//alert('insert called');
alert('before populate');
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
alert('before insert');
db.transaction(function(tx){                
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO deadlines (id, description, class, dueDate, dueTime, type, additionalInfo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[dbId,dbDescription,dbClass,dbDueDate, dbDueTime, dbType, dbAdditionalInfo],successCB, errorCB);
    alert(tx);
});
window.location.href = "deadlines.html"
}
```

I tried `window.location.replace` also but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put the redirect into a transaction specific callback for success and or failure as required ie.

Change the executeSQL line;

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO deadlines (id, description, class, dueDate, dueTime, type, additionalInfo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[dbId,dbDescription,dbClass,dbDueDate, dbDueTime, dbType, dbAdditionalInfo],successCbTx, errorCbTx);
```

Add specific functions for tx success and fail;

```
function successCbTx(){
    window.location.href = "deadlines.html";
}
function errorCbTx(){
    // logic as required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page will be redirected first so it will not store the data in database
so write a function for success it will automatically store the data.

```
function successCbTx(){

    window.location.href = "deadlines.html";
}
```

or

```
function successCbTx(){

    $(location).attr('href','deadlines.html');

}
```

will also work.